# How to restrict Github Post-Receive WebHook to master branch only

Tags: github

Question is pretty much self explanatory. I want that the webhook will be triggered on commits to master branch only, I might be wrong, but from my experience right now it seems to be triggered on commit to every branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that you don't have much control over a [GitHub post-receive hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks), it seems easier to filter the JSON message representing the payload of said hook.

You can check the value of the "`ref`" element

```
"ref":"refs/heads/master",
```

Any part of the JSON message which don't include the expected ref could be ignored by your listener.

Comment: Do I need to change the GitHub-Plugin for this ? Or where can I check the value of "ref" without any change in the original plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same problem, and while I couldn't find a solution that solves it as asked, I did find a workaround that was acceptable to the team requesting this feature.

Assuming you would only want to build master after merging changes in, you can tag that commit as a Release in GitHub. Then update the GitHub webhook to only send a build trigger when a Release is published, instead of when any push is made to the GitHub repo.